# MSBuild execution of Powershell Script file relative / absolute path

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have a power shell script that I want to run with MSBuild. The script itself works and I can pass the path variables in with the command line; however, when I attempt to pass the variables in through MSbuild I get errors in the path.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\PowershellTask\Powershell.targets"/>

   <Target Name="Minify">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <FilePath>\Scripts</FilePath>
       <OutputPath>\MinifiedJS</OutputPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Exec Command= "powershell.exe -command &quot;&amp;.\MinifyCSS.ps1&apos;$(FilePath)&apos;&apos;$(OutputPath)&apos;}&quot;" />
```

How to I pass the path into MSBuild. The above code errors on /Scripts and /MinifiedJS.
Here is the error:

powershell.exe -command "&{.\MinifyCSS.ps1'/Scripts''/MinifiedJS'}"
The term '.\MinifyCSS.ps1/Scripts'/MinifiedJS' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:41 + &{.\MinifyCSS.ps1'/Scripts''/MinifiedJS' <<<< } + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\MinifyCSS.ps1/Scripts'/MinifiedJS:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I also tried place them in quotes and using .\ prior.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Try replacing the `.\ ` with the actual path to the script.  I think the powershell.exe command is creating a new session, that is starting at the default path, not the current path, so `.\MinifyCSS.ps1` doesn't exist from the path powershell.exe is starting from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\PowershellTask\Powershell.targets"/>
<Target Name="Minify">
<PropertyGroup>
<FilePath>\Scripts</FilePath>
<OutputPath>\MinifiedJS</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="powershell.exe .\MinifyCSS.ps1 Scripts MinifiedJS" />
</Target>
</Project>
```